# I want to update information in a class based on function output. I want this to happen .onAppear

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I want to update the variable caloriesPerHour when the screen appears with the return of func calculateCaloriesPerHour.

I left a space for the .onAppear code (I am assuming thats where the code should go?)

Thank you for the help.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI
```

this is the class I want updated:

```
class FastingCalculation: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var mealSize = 200
    @Published var caloriesPerHour: Int = 70

}
```

This is the function I want to run

```
func calculateCaloriesPerHour() -> Int {
    let meal = FastingCalculation()
    let user = UserDetails()
    let cPH = user.dailycalories/meal.mealSize
    return cPH
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var lastMeal = FastingCalculation()
    @ObservedObject var userInfo = UserDetails()
```

I am assuming this is the function where the magic happens

```
    func onAppear() {
        // Run calculateCaloriesPerHour function
        // Make var caloriesPerHour = calculateCalroiesPerHour()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text ("Hello \(userInfo.username)")
                .font(.headline)
            
            Text("Enter the size of you last meal:")
                .font(.body)
            
            Picker(selection: $lastMeal.mealSize, label: Text("")) {
                Text("200").tag(200)
                Text("300").tag(300)
                Text("400").tag(400)
                Text("500").tag(500)
                Text("600").tag(600)
                Text("700").tag(700)
                Text("800").tag(800)
                Text("900").tag(900)
                Text("1000").tag(1000)
                Text("1100").tag(1100)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            NavigationLink(destination: TimerView()) {
                Text("Start Fasting")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue may originate from a possible misunderstanding of `.onAppear`. While your code references `onAppear` as a function, it's typically a [*modifier*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view).

For example:

```
Text("When this text appears, it will call onAppear!")
    .onAppear {
        print("onAppear has been called... now what?")
    }
```

However, if you insist on using your onAppear function, you could just call it directly from the modifier, like so:

```
Text("When this text appears, it will call onAppear()!")
    .onAppear {
        self.onAppear()
    }
```

Now, to *update* your class, it's just as easy:

```
.onAppear {
    self.lastMeal.mealSize = 2000
    self.lastMeal.caloriesPerHour = 4000
    let someComplexCalculation = calculateCaloriesPerHour()
    print(someComplexCualculation)
    
}
```

Excellent, while this does update the input values, and automatically trigger a state change because of the `@Published` wrapper, we still haven't supplied a way to display the result of `someComplexCalculation` in the view.

This can be easily accomplished by adding a @State variable into the view, right by the @ObservedObject declarations:

```
@State calculatedValue = "please enter in you data"
```

And then displaying it in your view:

```
VStack {
    Text("Your calculated value is:")
    Text(self.calculatedValue)
}
```

Don't forget to set it inside the previously mentioned onAppear statement:

```
.onAppear {
    let someComplexCalculation = calculateCaloriesPerHour()
    self.calculatedValue = someComplexCalculation
}
```

---

### Note

I noticed that you are initializing new values inside `calculateCaloriesPerHour`:

```
let meal = FastingCalculation()
let user = UserDetails()
```

This won't calculate the results based on the data you receive from the user, if you would like to change this, try moving the function into ContentView, and also make it reference the stored values:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
     func calculateCaloriesPerHour() -> Int {
        let meal = self.lastMeal
        let user = self.userInfo
        let cPH = user.dailycalories/meal.mealSize
        return cPH
     }
```

---

Have fun coding! If you are new to Swift and SwiftUI I highly suggest to check out the 100 day tutorial by my good friend† Paul:

[Tutorial that helped me](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui)

† I am not affiliated with Paul whatsoever.

Comment: Hey! I actually can't believe I got this response! THANK YOU! I will try to reflect your comment.
I have a different view that I will create which will show the results.
I can't thank you enough for helping me :')

Comment: Oh one more thing, I tried using the .onAppear as a modifier... for some reason, it is not giving me an autofill for it, so I am assuming its not working... I will try again, maybe I was just trying to stick it in the wrong place.

Comment: Try adding it to the closing brace of the `VStack`: `VStack {...}.onAppear {...}`

Comment: Just wanted to quickly say thank you again, I restructured my code and implemented what you said, and now I overcome that challenge :D on to the next one :D